# What are the differences in the various words for "or"?

Tags: vocabulary

Google translate suggests "또는".
Pimsleur has, I believe, "나", or something that sounds like "na" at least.
Finally, the Drops app on android uses "혹은" (sounds like the name "Hogan" in English).
I don't doubt that there could be others after finding three, but what are the different implications of using each of these (and any others)?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `또는` or `혹은` pretty much interchangeably. That is, both can be used as enumeration and conjunction. You can also use `아니면` (often casually shortened as `아님`) in the same sense.

> 1. 커피 혹은/또는/아니면 차 드시겠어요? (Would you like some coffee or tea?)
> 2. 커피가 좋겠습니다. 혹은/또는/아니면 그냥 물도 좋습니다. (I'd like coffee. Or just water, please)

However, `-나` is only for enumeration.

> 3. 커피나 차 드시겠어요? (Would you like some coffee or tea?)
> 4. 커피가 좋겠습니다. **나 그냥 물도 좋습니다.*

Note that `-나` is actually not an independent word, but an inflective suffix. In the above example, it is used as a marker for a noun (`커피`+`-나`). 나 can also be used in conjugating predicates in a similar way but usually in a slightly different form, `-거나`.

> 5. 커피 드시*거나* 잡지 보시겠어요? (Would you like to drink some coffee or to read magazines?)

> 6. 이러*나* 저러*나* 마찬가지네요. (It's the same either this way or another)

Finally, when enumerating, you can use 나 and one of the above words together or mixed, but this has no significant changes in meaning.

> 7. 커피 드시*거나* *아니면* 잡지 보시겠어요? (Would you like to drink some coffee or to read magazines?)

> 8. 차갑*거나* 뜨거운 커피*나* *또는* 차 드시겠어요? (Would you like some coffee or tea either hot or cold?)

Answer (score 2):

`또는`, `혹은` sounds a little formal.

> 대중교통 또는 자가용

> 참 또는 거짓

> 진실 혹은 거짓

`나`, `거나` are informal.

> 그러거나 말거나.

> 초코맛이나 딸기맛

Also there are `든가`, `든지` as even more casual form of `or`.

> 그러든가 말든가. (신경 안 쓴다.)

> 그러든지 말든지. (신경 안 쓴다.)

> 뒈지든지 말든지.

> 초코맛이라든가 딸기맛이라든가

> 초코맛이든지 딸기맛이든지 다 좋아.